# Filter a array of objects that do not match any of the members of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo

I have the following data.  I would like to be able to efficiently filter out all of the objects in the `sites` array that do not have a matching `segmentCode` in array of `segmentCodes`.  I can use dojo or native javascript, but I do not have access to any other libraries.

```
var segmentCodes = ["10", "20","30","40"];
var sites = [
    {"siteid":1, "segmentCode":"10"},
    {"siteid":2, "segmentCode":"10"},
    {"siteid":3, "segmentCode":"20"},
    {"siteid":4, "segmentCode":"30"},
    {"siteid":5, "segmentCode":"70"},
    {"siteid":6, "segmentCode":"999"}];
```

The result should look like this:

> [{"siteid":5, "segmentCode":"70"}, {"siteid":6, "segmentCode":"999"}]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint : look for "indexOf" and "filter" in the MDN.

Comment: I was going to try dojo.filter and then a for loop for each segmentCode, but I don't think that would be fast enough.

Comment: How many sites do you have ? There's no really faster solutions for short arrays.

Comment: I've got about 3,000-4,000 sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)

```
var res = sites.filter(function( o){
  return segmentCodes.indexOf(o.segmentCode) == -1;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8FTA/)**

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution would be to convert `segmentCodes` into a map:

```
map = segmentCodes.reduce(function(o, x) { return o[x] = 1, o }, {})
```

and then use an O(1) lookup to filter the codes:

```
result = sites.filter(function(x) { return !(x.segmentCode in map) })
```

If you want this to be even faster, replace iterator functions with plain loops.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the proper solution with Dojo would be using the `dojo/_base/array` module. For example:

```js
require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(arrayUtils) {
    arrayUtils.filter(sites, function(site) {
        return arrayUtils.indexOf(segmentCodes, site.segmentCode) < 0;
    });
});
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/pwzTN/).

Answer (score 0):

CLJ!
Check this out!

```
var segmentCodes = ["10", "20","30","40"];
var sites = [
    {"siteid":1, "segmentCode":"10"},
    {"siteid":2, "segmentCode":"10"},
    {"siteid":3, "segmentCode":"20"},
    {"siteid":4, "segmentCode":"30"},
    {"siteid":5, "segmentCode":"70"},
    {"siteid":6, "segmentCode":"999"}];
var segmentCodes = ["10", "20","30","40"];

Array.prototype.filter = function(fun, notMatchArray) {
    'use strict';

    if (!this) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var objects = Object(this);
    var len = objects.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i in objects) {
      if (objects.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if(notMatchArray.indexOf(objects[i].segmentCode) === -1)
            res.push(objects[i]);
      }
    }
    fun.call(thisp, res);
};

sites.filter(function(result){
    console.log('result', result);
}, segmentCodes);
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter